# Openmeeting enter room is not working

Tags: ajax, rest, openmeetings

I am trying to below link for integrating openmeetings(version 3.2.1) with my application.

http://openmeetings.apache.org/RestAPISample.html

Requirement is need to access openmeetings without signin page, as describe in above link.

As per link, I am getting SID successfully, but last link to enter into the room

http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/swf?secureHash=fa1f9381-bd03-42ae-9fd9-332b5f775a1b&language=1 
 is not working.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What are you starting from and integrating with OpenMeetings? Also, you say it is "not working": is there a specific message you can show in your post?

Comment: Hi.. I am facing the same problem... In my case login screen is showing when trying to enter in room using hash.. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated http://openmeetings.apache.org/RestAPISample.html

URL for 3.2.1 should be changed

You need to use

http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/hash?secure=fa1f9381-bd03-42ae-9fd9-332b5f775a1b&language=1

instead of

http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/swf?secureHash=fa1f9381-bd03-42ae-9fd9-332b5f775a1b&language=1

Comment: hi Maxim, thanks for your help, It works like a charm. I am able to move at the room with rest calls.

Comment: hi, Im using the specified url but getting the access denied message.
I think the problem is externalUserDto which I don't what is it and how should I fill the dto, but getting the room hash successfully.

Comment: please examine the example: https://openmeetings.apache.org/RestAPISample.html it is very much self explained :)